# change to main thread, from another thread in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5

is there a way to shift to main thread from a background thread, for example;

```
import threading

def func(txt):
    if txt == 'foo':
        ## must do the processing in the main thread
        pass

    else:
        print(txt)


thread = threading.Thread(target = func, args = ('hello',))
thread.start()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable in mainthread which will be changed in func. Then check in main the status of the variable.

If foo, then do something.

Comment: Yeah, okay, imagine having an infinite loop in the Thread "thread" , and even if you call some other function inside the Thread "thread" it will execute in the Thread "thread" and not in "main_thread", I need a way to completely change to main thread.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood me. Set a variable in main thread which you change in thread. For this need probably global variablename